# Pairing my own UIPanGestureRecognizer with that of UIScrollView's

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have two views; a `UIView` placed on top of a `UITableView`. I need to know when the `UIView` has been panned, so I’ve placed a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on it. However, this creates a UI which seems buggy because you expect the `UITableView` behind it to move as your finger does.

So it seems I need to somehow pair up this pan gesture with making the table view behind it move, at least, until this covering view disappears.

How do I pair up a pan gesture to move a `UIScrollView`?

Note: If you’re wondering about the cover view, it’s actually a `UIImageView` which has a snapshot of the table view with a filter applied to it for UI reasons.
When this view is panned, it disappears. So from the user’s point of view, while they begin dragging the cover view, I want them to keep thinking they are dragging the table view as the cover disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a view controller with a table view setup like the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate 
{

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

You can add a couple of gesture recognizers:

```
    var gestureRecognizer1: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
    var gestureRecognizer2: UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
```

Setup your delegates and add the gesture recognizers to the scroll views:

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake( ) // <-- Set your content size.
        scrollView.delegate = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        gestureRecognizer1.delegate = self
        gestureRecognizer2.delegate = self
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer1)
        scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer2)
    }
```

Implement a delegate method for `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to recognize simultaneous gestures:

```
    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }
```

Implement a delegate method for `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) 
    {
        tableView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    }
}
```

The movement of the tableView will be synchronized to the scroll view.

Comment: I thought this too, but when I set the delegate of `UITableView`’s `panGesture` to my `UIViewController` (I’m not using `UITableViewController`) then my app crashes because `panGesture`’s delegate should be the `UIScrollView`

Comment: `UIScrollView` already has a `panGestureRecognizer`. Are you able to use it to get the behavior that you want instead of adding another one?

Comment: If you’re talking about taking `panGestureRecognizer` off the scroll view and putting it on another view that can’t be a good solution!

Comment: I can move the `UIScrollView`’s content offset with the custom pan gesture’s translation, but then I don’t get all the nice stuff that comes with UIScrollView like bouncing and velocity.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution that synchronizes the movement of the table view and the scroll view. The table view motion will mirror the scroll view motion including bouncing and velocity. You had the right idea about adding a pan gesture recognizer.

Comment: Thanks, but in the end I’ve decided to directly change the cell’s images with a `CIFilter` rather than take a snapshot. This way is the way I should have done it anyway, it’s much cleaner and uses no possibly-buggy “workarounds"

Comment: Great, Adam. I'm glad you found a solution that you are happy with.

Comment: Yeah I only came up the idea a few minutes before commenting so I couldn’t post any sooner haha. Thanks for helping though :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I’ve decided to directly change the cell’s images with a `CIFilter` rather than take a snapshot. This way is the way I should have done it anyway, it’s much cleaner and uses no possibly-buggy “workarounds”.